# C++ OpenCV boundRect[].tl() unit of output

Tags: c++, opencv

I was wondering what the unit is of my boundRect[].tl() output.

```
topleft = boundRect[largest_contour_index].tl();
```

My assumption is that it is in pixels.
If so, do I need to look at the pixels of my camera and the format it outputs to calculate the position of my object? 
Or do the pixels that the function outputs change due to the fact that OpenCV converts the image to an 8-bit image? I can imagine that the amount of pixels where the image consists of becomes smaller when the image is converted to 8 bit.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: is in pixels... _"I can imagine that the amount of pixels where the image consists of becomes smaller when the image is converted to 8 bit"_ NO. it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `BoundingRect` returns x,y coordinates, width and height. you can refer to its documentation:    [docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect](http://%20docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect)

second, the 8-bit image conversion was based on pixel value of color and doesn't have a direct relation with pixel count. So converting a 100x100 image to 8-bit image will still be 100x100 px